# How long are stripe SetUpIntent objects stored for?

Tags: stripe-payments

In the docs (https://stripe.com/docs/api/setup_intents/object) there is no mention of the object being destroyed after a certain time period. Is it safe to assume that they won't be destroyed unless they are explicitly cancelled?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct, SetupIntents have no expiration. The only way to cancel a SetupIntent is to explicitly call the [cancel endpoint](https://stripe.com/docs/api/setup_intents/cancel).

Note that the same is true for PaymentIntents.

Comment: Is there a part of Stripe's docs that says there's no expiration? The [docs page](https://stripe.com/docs/api/setup_intents) for setup intents states that long-lived setup intents can become invalid, so it seems there's some type of expiry mechanism.

Comment: Confirmed from stripe support that they have no expiraton.